# Angular : How to access Value of Class using Form Name

Tags: angular

I am trying to access the class name of form control using Form Name both in HTML and in Class file

The below works find and displays the value of the control

```
{{ModelForm.value.firstName| json}}
```

But, If I try to print the value of class "valid", it errors out

```
{{ModelForm.value.firstName.valid | json}}
```

Error says :

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

Similarly, I need to access the same value in Class file

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.ModelForm.get('firstName').valid);
  }
```

This also is erroring out

[image]

here is the code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ps9aeb

Comment: When is ```ModelForm.value.firstName``` being set? Probably you're trying to access the property ```valid``` before it's loaded. Have you tried the elvis operator (?) like ```{{ModelForm.value.firstName?.valid | json}}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a safe navigator so it will not throw an error if first name control is undefined:

```
<br>
    {{ ModelForm.form.controls.firstName?.valid | json }}
<br>
```

Comment: Thank you Devang,
Also, How to I access the same Value in the class file ?
If I print :
    console.log (this.ModelForm.form.controls.firstName?.valid)

It gives error :
error TS2339: Property 'ModelForm' does not exist on type 'ModelFormComponent'.